# Merge guest quote items to customer quote(if customer log in) by magento 2 rest API

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, magento2.3.2

If any one is add products in cart by guest and after that login then how it will merge guest cart to customer login cart items by Rest API. if anyone found this solutions, please help me.

I have already try below code but it's not working:

```
Method - PUT 
{URL}/rest/V1/guest-carts/{guest-card-id} 
Param - { 
"customerId": 3, 
"storeId": 1 
} 
Authorization -"Bearer {user-token}"
```

Not found any solution yet. if anyone know about this then please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bring some light on it, I think the method you mentioned should work after the fix of https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/24808.

I created an extension to fix this issue for the Magento version < 2.3.4. https://github.com/troublediehard/plab-cartsmergefix

Comment: if you check name then, this issue is posted by me :-)

Comment: Yes, I did. But it will be useful for new people looking for this question.

Comment: @SangeetaJain I created an extension which uses this fix for the Magento version < 2.3.4

Comment: Also, thank you for raising this issue on the GitHub, now we have solution because of your effort.